# How do I interpret the indirect effect when path a is a linear link and path b is a logistic link?

Tags: logistic, interpretation, mediation

I have a simple mediation model $X \rightarrow M \rightarrow Y$ (the direct effect $X \rightarrow Y$ is also specified).

$Y$ is a binary variable, and $X$ and $M$ are continuous variables. Because of this the path $X \rightarrow M$ is using a linear link, and the path $M \rightarrow Y$ is using a logistic link. Given the logit coefficient $b$, I know that one unit of change in $M$ predicts change of $b$ in $logit(Y)$.

However, I also have the linear coefficient $a$ from $X \rightarrow M$. What is the correct way to interpret the indirect effect $ab$ in regards of relating a one unit change in $X$ to the change in $logit(Y)$? Is it safe to consider $ab$ as a logit coefficient?

Comment: You need to look into the causal mediation literature, which addresses this issue exactly. Imai, Keele, Tingley, & Yamamoto (2011) and Valeri & VanderWeele (2013) are good introductory articles that address this very point and the limitations of the classic mediation approach (i.e., product of coefficients approach). Causal mediation interpretation is not tied to any statistical model.

Comment: @Noah Thank you for introducing me the relevant articles. It seems I need something else than the product of coefficients approach.